# mysql stored procedure wont return results

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE catalog_get_category_products(IN inCategoryId INT)
BEGIN
SELECT     p.product_id, p.name, p.description, p.price
FROM       product p
INNER JOIN product_category pc
           ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
WHERE      pc.category_id = inCategoryId
ORDER BY   p.product_id;
END$$
```

this my stored procedure when executed it returns nothing despite of category having products, cant seem to understand where m going wrong any pointers to solve this.
when executed the above procedure, it should return the products associated with that category

Comment: Does the query when run by itself (not within `BEGIN ... END`) returns the expected result ?

Comment: Your proc will not return anything as you have not defined an OUT parameter. You are just doing some computation/querying and not fetching the result back.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

Initial setup of tables and test data (you shouldn't have to do this part; it's just for reference):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product
(
    product_id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50),
    description varchar(50),
    price decimal(10, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product_category
(
    product_id int,
    category_id int,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id, category_id)
);

INSERT INTO product VALUES (1, 'Shirt', 'long-sleeve blue shirt', 15.99)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id = product_id;

INSERT product_category VALUES (1, 23)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id = product_id;
```

Stored proc setup (try this part and see it works for you):

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS catalog_get_category_products;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE catalog_get_category_products
(
    inCategoryId INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT     p.product_id, p.name, p.description, p.price
    FROM       product p
    INNER JOIN product_category pc
               ON p.product_id = pc.product_id
    WHERE      pc.category_id = inCategoryId
    ORDER BY   p.product_id;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Calling the stored proc (replace the `23` with a valid `category_id` that is associated with at least one valid `product_id` in the `product_category` table):

```
CALL catalog_get_category_products(23);
```

Comment: i Dnt knw how but after using the drop proc if exists , m able to get results from the proc. for the initial code that was posted . Thank yu Troy